# Implement openldap server in mirror mode

Tags: openldap

here is my config on `slapd.conf` in server01:

```
    serverID    1
    # database section

    # syncrepl directive
    syncrepl      rid=002
        provider=ldap://192.168.100.193
        bindmethod=simple
        binddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local"
        credentials=123
        searchbase="dc=example,dc=local"
        schemachecking=on
        type=refreshAndPersist
        retry="60 +"
        overlay syncprov
        syncprov-checkpoint 50 1
        syncprov-sessionlog 50
    mirrormode on
```

and here is my config on `slapd.conf` on server02:

```
 serverID    2
# database section

# syncrepl directive
syncrepl      rid=002
        provider=ldap://192.168.100.139
        bindmethod=simple
        binddn="cn=admin,dc=example,dc=local"
        credentials=123
        searchbase="dc=example,dc=local"
        schemachecking=on
        type=refreshAndPersist
        retry="60 +"
mirrormode on
```

then use **`slaptest`** command to generate the config files `(slaptest -f config-file -F /etc/ldap/slapd.d/)` and replace them with the default files in the `/etc/ldap/slapd.d` path in both servers.
then restart the slapd service and everything is ok.
but when i add entry to the both servers they don't sync data with each other.

after these steps i am try to capture the packets and found out they found all of the entries of the another server.

ps: sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer that works in my scenario:

copy the  `/usr/share/slapd/slapd.conf` and add these configs:

first-server:

```
include         /etc/ldap/schema/core.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /etc/ldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema

moduleload      back_mdb
moduleload      accesslog.la
moduleload      syncprov.la

overlay syncprov
syncprov-checkpoint 100 10
syncprov-sessionlog 100

serverID    1

syncrepl      rid=001
        provider=ldap://<second-server>
        bindmethod=simple
        binddn="cn=admin,dc=part,dc=local"
        credentials=123
        searchbase="dc=part,dc=local"
        scope=sub
        schemachecking=on
        type=refreshAndPersist
        retry="60 +"
mirrormode on
```

seconds server:
as like as the above, just edit the `serverID`.
and voila...